# JPA validation in Eclipse 2018/12 defective? - complains about LOWER keyword

Tags: eclipse, validation, jpa

In the latest Eclipse version, the JPA validation seems to make odd things. It complains about the following expression:

[image: lower expression]

The error says:

> The IN expression does not have a valid left expression.

In my opinion this is wrong. The query works as expected, so this seems to be an Eclipse bug, right? Or do you have another idea, why this error occurs?

I'm not sure if this error comes from the JBoss tools or directly from Eclipse validation. I can say that it is this validator:

[image: Validator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition - that is [the JPA specification](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf)¹ document aka JSR 338 - JPQL allows for functions such as `LOWER(..)`. These are defined as "reserved identifiers" (see *Section 4.4.1 Identifiers*, p. 172):

> The following are reserved identifiers:
>
> ABS, ALL, AND, ANY, AS, ASC, AVG, BETWEEN,
>   BIT_LENGTH[59], BOTH, BY, CASE, CHAR_LENGTH, CHARACTER_LENGTH, CLASS, COALESCE, CONCAT, COUNT, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   DELETE, DESC, DISTINCT, ELSE, EMPTY, END, ENTRY, ESCAPE, EXISTS, FALSE, FETCH,
>   FROM, FUNCTION, GROUP, HAVING, IN, INDEX, INNER, IS, JOIN, KEY, LEADING, LEFT,
>   LENGTH, LIKE, LOCATE, **LOWER**, MAX, MEMBER, MIN, MOD, NEW, NOT, NULL, NULLIF,
>   OBJECT, OF, ON, OR, ORDER, OUTER, POSITION, SELECT, SET, SIZE, SOME, SQRT, SUBSTRING, SUM, THEN, TRAILING, TREAT, TRIM, TRUE, TYPE, UNKNOWN, UPDATE, UPPER,
>   VALUE, WHEN, WHERE.

In section *4.6.17.2.1 String Functions*, on page 193f, the function `LOWER(string_expression)` is described more detailed. The JPA spec document states:

> The **LOWER** and UPPER functions convert a string to lower and upper case, respectively, with regard to the locale of the database. They return a string.

As a consequence, the *BNF* of the JPA query language defines LOWER as a keyword.

### Conclusion

A bug in Eclipse, the respective JPA query validators, or other tooling seems very likely for the version(s) you have installed. You might consider checking Eclipse's bug tracker or an upgrade to Eclipse 2019+.

Hope it helps.

--

¹ In version 2.2 or the previous version 2.1/2.0